# Resample Unbalanced sequence data in deep learning doesn't have good effect?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes, resampling

I'm working on text classification using a deep learning approach. Because the data I use has unbalanced conditions, I try to implement data balancing techniques using the imblearn library.

However, instead of getting better results, I ended up getting really bad results after oversampling or undersampling.

Say on the original data I get 85% accuracy with 5 epochs. After resampling, I got 3% accuracy with 5 epochs. Then, I tried to use a larger epoch for resampled data, and I got 78% accuracy with 15 epochs, then I got >80% accuracy with 25 epochs. Does this make sense? I mean, I even get better results without doing any data balancing techniques.

But I've also tried it on shallow learning algorithms, and data balancing techniques had a good effect.

Can anyone explain this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give some details about the dataset, resampling technique, the type of layers and architecture you are using. You might consider that resampling (ex. imputation) might causes underestimated statistic (ex. variance) which might lead to such behavior, also you might try to shuffle your data after resampling.

Comment: @4.Pi.n I use adasyn, smote, and a few other techniques. For classification, I use LSTM and CNN. You can see a sample of my work using ADASYN here  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KOz_eLokA6SB9oJNuGLpgk9H2kF80O3r?usp=sharing
Can you help to check it? thank you

Comment: `Epoch 1/15 - loss=15.2539, val_loss=364.6949, train_acc=0.58, val_acc=0.13`, that's **overfitting**. In addition, dataset  quite small, given the dimension of words embedding (number of features) - `(4854, 45000)`, reduce number of hidden units for the second layer `Linear`, you might try dropout ratio in a range `[0.3, 0.6]`, `k-fold cross validation` is preferred over train-test-split.

Comment: @4.Pi.n Thank you very much for checking out and making suggestions.
So, does that mean I need to use a different neural network architecture for resampled data? As I said before, the original data with the same architecture had good performance with only 5 epochs.

I can apply k-fold cross validation to the original data, but when resampling the dataset I was confused about applying it, because based on the references I read, I have to resample the data while doing cross validation.

Comment: Try to use Kfolds cross validation for the original data, I guess the problem has nothing to do with resampling itself, both models might overfit, train-test-split for original data is non representative evaluation of how good model it is, especially in case of imbalanced dataset, as loss of rare examples not too much (has less influential), so you might not be able to capture the overfitting for original data too. You might need to consider how to solve overfitting problem in general (for original or resampled data).